# Fit image button perfectly on Android?

Tags: android, resolution

I'm developing a scheduling app.

The main activity is going to have 3 ImageButtons which fill the entire screen and I did the correct dimension calculation.

I'm using a Nexus 7 so the dimensions are `1920x1200`, which means each button is going to be `640x1200`.  The only problem is that the image doesn't fit correctly and I get a funky warped effect.  Where as the button should look like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qfcInBn.jpg]

It looks squished like this:

[image: http://gyazo.com/2b70364db199dfcdcc3247c1ab302ed0]

Does anyone know the simplest way I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to make the height fill_parent ?

Comment: Can you put your xml here ?

Comment: Please show your xml here.

Answer (score 0):

Use scaleType for image to fit for screen.

Better use centercrop for image.

Refer [Documentation here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Here is an example for each scaletype with image. Hope this might help you.

http://etcodehome.blogspot.in/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Answer (score 0):

Move your background resource file under `drawable-xhdpi` folder